# HighCharts gantt treegrid collapse details

Tags: highcharts, gantt-chart

While implementing HC gantt chart with tree grid and sub tasks I noticed that in the samples collapsing an item with children would show the details of the children, but not always.

Looking at standard project management example (jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/gantt/demo/project-management) if we collapse the "New Offices" node, it will show a summary of the children underneath, but if we collapse the "New Product launch" node, then it doesn't show any details. Why are those 2 nodes performing differently? In my case I'm never seeing details but this might help find the required conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug, which has been already reported and fixed. Should be fine in the next release.

See: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12617

Comment: Am I getting it right that the behavior of version 7 (not showing collapsed as flatten child) is the fix? I kind of liked the "summary" row.

Comment: Actually, this 'summary' row was an unexpected effect after some changes in the core, probably these: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/commit/65d82368ddc19a1e45579e1c78c8d6ee3e3d2226 , so yes, after fix this row will be hidden. If you like this 'feature' feel free to share your idea with the Highcharts core developers in the discussion in the above issue link or you can report it on Highcharts userVoice channel: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api